# giving commands to R from C# without using RDotNet

Tags: c#, r

I managed to open R from C# using the process.Start command, but when I give another file to the process.start, where I wrote the commands for R, the file is just ignored.

```
Process.Start("C:/Program Files (x86)/R/R-3.1.1/bin/i386/R", "C:/Users/diego/Documents/Proyectos/Polynomials.txt");
```

The first argument calls R, the second one is the file with the commands. Is there any way I can call R and directly issue commands to it from C#?

Comment: you should call RScript.exe with the argument of your R script file

Comment: also any real reason to use the 32 bit process?

Comment: I had been using the 64 bit process before, but I was trying to do this with RDotNet, and it wasn't able to open my 64 bit process because of reasons I couldn't understand. Thanks for the answer.